# access index of list in the dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So here i have a list of numbers of 'Q9ULI0' id. Which is look like this:

```
['1117', '285', '357', '58', '813', '1398', '566']
```

when i call `print lookup['Q9ULI0']`
I am trying access all of those value in the index to see if the number is between two of my value. I tried using `.len` and for loop but it doesn't even compile. Thank you in advance.

```
lookup = defaultdict(list)

mydata = open('mydata.txt')

for line in csv.reader(mydata, delimiter='\t'):

    code = re.match('[a-z](\d+)[a-z]', line[-1], re.I)
    if code: 
        lookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(1))

print lookup['Q9ULI0']
```

Comment: "but it doesn't even compile" -- I assume you mean that there is a syntax error.  Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @mgilson i was testing to see whether i use lookup.len() or code.len() would give me the length of the list but it gives me this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'len'

Comment: @ChadD I think you want `len(lookup)` or `len(code)`

Comment: Ahh.  you could use `lookup.__len__()`, but it's probably easier to just do `len(lookup)`

Comment: @mgilson i guess i had my syntax wrong thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: But if you're getting an error that says that lookup and code are 'NoneType' objects, you've still got problems...

Comment: accessing any property that begins with `_` is frown upon in python, since its considered internal state, also note `match Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found`

Comment: @Ord -- code could be `None` if no match was found.

Comment: @samy.vilar -- I was really just joking about `lookup.__len__()` (sorry, I guess I should have been more explicit about it).  It was meant to hopefully help Chad learn what the `len` builtin is actually doing (i.e. calling `__len__` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to print `lookup['Q9ULI0']` and get the list that you have above, you should have no issues with the following code, which gets the length of the list and loops over it using `for`:

```
print len(lookup['Q9ULI0'])
for item in lookup['Q9ULI0']:
    print item
```